# Python populate list from a string with separator

Tags: python, configparser

I have a string which I am parsing using ConfigParser. This string contains some options for a process to run. I want to construct a List from this string.

```
argString="-i,1,-m,2,-trace,on,-setlimit,500"
argList=['-i','1','-m','2','-trace','on','-setlimit','500']
```

I am using this list to execute with subprocess Popen.
basically, how do I append a List by reading a string and given separator ','
or is there a better way to do it using ConfigParser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> argString="-i,1,-m,2,-trace,on,-setlimit,500"
>>> argString.split(",")
['-i', '1', '-m', '2', '-trace', 'on', '-setlimit', '500']
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
lst = argString.split(",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use split - e.g. `str.split`

```
>>> argList=argString.split(',');
>>> argList
['-i', '1', '-m', '2', '-trace', 'on', '-setlimit', '500'
```